# How to combine $BUILD_LOG_REGEX with $FILE in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-email-ext

I am retrieving the relative path to my HTML report from the console output using a build log regular expression on Jenkins.

How do I use the retrieved path in `${FILE,path}`?

For example, if my console output has the following content:

> STATUS        : FAIL LOG FILE :
>   /home/ashanmuga/regression_git/LOG/2018-01-03/fm_device_info.87/fm_device_info.log
>
> TEST SUITE REPORT FILE:
>   /home/ashanmuga/regression_git/REPORT/2018-01-03/rerun.report.85.html

With the following regular expression:

```
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="TEST SUITE REPORT FILE: (.*html)" , showTruncatedLines=false, substText="\"$1\""}
```

Gives the following output:

> /home/ashanmuga/regression_git/REPORT/2018-01-03/rerun.report.85.html

Combining a regular expression with the file command:

```
${FILE, path= ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="TEST SUITE REPORT FILE: (.*html)", showTruncatedLines=false, substText="\"$1\""}}
```

Gives the following output instead of attaching the report:

> ${FILE,path= "/home/ashanmuga/regression_git/REPORT/2018-01-03/rerun.report.85.html" }

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the token macro source code this is not possible because it does not allow macros to be used as part of arguments for other macros. You can attach the file to the email instead or if using a pipeline you can just do it in the groovy code